# pdflatex nonstopmode with TikZ stops compiling

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, compiling

I compiled a TikZ code using pdflatex `-interaction=nonstopmode`. Depending on code errors, compiling stops. I want to know what went wrong. Let me show you two cases, both of which involve a code error each.

Case 1: "`$`" is missing in the 6th line (`\node` at...). Compiling does NOT stop.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
     \begin{tikzpicture}
          \draw [help lines] (0,0) grid (2,2);
          \node at (1,1) {$x^2};
     \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Case 2: "`;`" is missing at the end of the 5th line (`\draw`...). Compiling STOPS. I have to press keys to continue.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
     \begin{tikzpicture}
          \draw [help lines] (0,0) grid (2,2)
          \node at (1,1) {$x^2$};
     \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Is Case 2 an expected result? If so, how can I make compiling non-stop? Your help is appreciated.

Comment: The same result (-.-).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Processing does not stop, it just goes into a tight loop

```
tikz@signal@path ->\tikz@signal@path 

\tikz@signal@path ->\tikz@signal@path 

\tikz@signal@path ->\tikz@signal@path 

\tikz@signal@path ->\tikz@signal@path 

\tikz@signal@path ->\tikz@signal@path 

[15]+  Stopped                 pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode
```

You can see this if you run the following with the `%` removed. **Beware** do not do this unless you are confident you can stop a misbehaving program: it will write an arbitrarily large log file until you stop it.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
%\tracingmacros1
%tracingonline1
     \begin{tikzpicture}
          \draw [help lines] (0,0) grid (2,2)
          \node at (1,1) {$x^2$};
     \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there any way to avoid such loop?

Comment: @T_T Not really. If you go `\def\foo{\foo}\foo` TeX will spin forever. and that is what ended up happening in this case. It is impossible to check in general that programs stop (the **halting problem**).

Comment: So we have to live with it...  Thanks for your input. Very much appreciated.

Comment: @T_T why would you want nonstopmode it is prone to such problems you can do `yes x |pdflatex -interaction=errorstopmode myfile`

Comment: Saving key strokes.. Perhaps, I am just lazy (^o^)/